# Text Adjustment in Css Dropdown Menu

Tags: css

I need your help once again, guys i'm struggling with a css dropdown menu in which i want to make text alignment top vertically, you can visit the link here:
http://www.kidsartvalley.com

Here that dropdown menus/lists can be viewed under the icons of messages/inbox, friends and notifications at the right side of boy(cartoon). Kindly make it possible for me to show text right on the top of each row's box so that image and text will be equally aligned.

Comment: I'm waiting for your quick response.. plz help me!!

Comment: Kamran, this is not "tech support", and you only asked your question 5 minutes ago. You don't need to add these type of comments. Just be patient and you will receive help, but next time try to include your code or a screenshot so others can benefit from this post. By the time you fix your site, this question will be meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:left` to your images inside these boxes. This will result in:

```
#### Name commented on
#### your awesome job
####
```

<sub>Rather than the current situation:

`####`

`####`

`#### Name commented on`

`your awesome job`</sub>

Comment: ok .. i've done it but kindly have a look at the result of this editing.. and advice!! thanks

Comment: Add `min-height:50px` to the anchors (`<a>`) within the same box.